# How to check MySQL is running in GTID mode or not?

Tags: mysql, database, replication, mysql-5.7, gtid

In MySQL-5.7,  we have both GTID and Traditional methods to setup MySQL replication.

We also have a new parameter:

> gtid_mode = ON_PERMISSIVE

which means we can enable the GTID but also able to run replication in traditional way.

Now we have enabled the MySQL replication but how we can check that mysql replication is working over GTID or Traditional ?

Thanks

Comment: can you check `gtid_executed`? this should hold a complete log of al the `GTID` Transactions. see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-gtids.html

Answer (score 2):

If:

```sql
show global variables like 'gtid_executed';
-- OR respectively:
select @@gtid_executed; -- @@ returns Globally set variables, single @ returns session set variables
```

returns a Value, you are using GTID

If it does not, you are using "Traditional" replication

Answer (score 0):

Check GTID is on both nodes for replication

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'gtid_mode';
```

Check masters GTID present in slave:

```
show global variables like 'gtid_executed'; <!---Should be same as master--->
```

You can check the replication working by running following commands

```
SHOW REPLICA STATUS\G;
```

In the output check

```
Replica_IO_Running: Yes
Replica_SQL_Running: Yes
Executed_Gtid_Set: <!--- ID present in slave is also present in master --->
```

**Reference** For implementing Mysql Multi Source Master Slave Replication: https://www.svastikkka.com/2024/03/mysql-multi-source-master-slave.html

Answer (score -1):

From MySQL [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-replication-excerpt/5.7/en/replication-mode-change-online-concepts.html):

*When `gtid_mode=OFF_PERMISSIVE` then new transactions are anonymous while permitting replicated transactions to be either GTID or anonymous transactions. When `gtid_mode=ON_PERMISSIVE` then new transactions use GTIDs while permitting replicated transactions to be either GTID or anonymous transactions*

This mean that `gtid_mode = ON PERMISSIVE` allows to have transactions with anonymous replication (traditional way) although new transactions are being made with GTID, that's why new version allows topology with GTID or anonymous replication.

This will help you with your request:

*Fields that display a single GTID, such as CURRENT_TRANSACTION in the replication_applier_status_by_worker Performance Schema table, now display ANONYMOUS when GTID transactions are not being used.*

Regards